# Why does my threejs map render outside of the visible extent of the browser?

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs, three-js

I created a [3d visualization using qgis2threejs](http://njander.github.io/threejs1/) but the map renders outside the visible extent of the browser window so I have to pull it down into the window each time.

Is there a way to change the rendering height in the .js file or something like that?  If so can you explain what parameter I would need to change?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the threejs, I would first say check out the element that is housing your map and see what the CSS settings are for it.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a CSS problem (I believe the issue is the 3d object itself is really high in the scene and needs to be rotated into the scene -- as opposed to be rendered outside the extents of a div or whatever).

When the plane is initialized in threeJS, check to see if a Y value is being assigned.  If it is, you may need to lower this value (even into the negatives) to offset the height of the plane in the scene so that it starts near the center.  If it is not being assigned, you can simply set the Y to a negative value (or whatever works) to offset the plane in the scene to be in view.